# Comparing different decimal places

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to match latitude `DECIMAL (10,8)` and longitude `DECIMAL (11,8)` in my database by latitude and longitude that only have 4 decimal places. I'm trying to compare addresses but since addresses are all in different formats, I figured latitude and longitude is the next best thing.

So right now I have to do this:

```
select *
from locations
where (latitude BETWEEN 33.29940 AND 33.29949) AND 
(longitude BETWEEN -111.89889 AND -111.89880)
```

Where I search between 0 and 9 of each number.  But it's pretty clunky.  I'd rather be able to do something like `LIKE %33.2994%` instead.

So what's the best way (performance-wise and easy to read) to search these latitude and longitude fields?

Comment: You could just cast the column data to the precision you want for the comparison.

Comment: Yea I guess I could do that.  Looks like cast rounds it up.  Just wanted to check if there was a better way.

Comment: Are you trying to find locations within a rectangle, IOW between two lat/long pairs? Or are you trying to find locations by proximity? If its the later, there's a formula that given two lat/long pairs returns the distance between them. That is good for searching for rows where the distance is less than x (miles/kilometers) from a given point.